# How do I make the letters seem as a part of the entire type set?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, typography, typefaces, font-design

---

**Tldr; Help me identify elements/qualities in "I" that makes it seem belonged to this set**

---

Greetings

I am a design enthusiast, and to understand typefaces, I started 36 days of type.

### Objective

The theme/objective is to create a bulky font, (heavy shapes with consistent thin flourishes.)

---

[image: Current type set]

---

### Process / Problem

While early explorations in illustrator, I liked the results with blend tool the most.

1. I started with a cell of size 9x9px and created a grid
2. For each letter I set the max dimensions to be 16 cells by 16 cells [image]
3. I wanted the shapes to be closed and have balance (I achieved this by introducing negative space in the shape by tweaking the outline, the stroke weights and blend options).
   [image]
4. "E" was the letter where the problem started, I couldn't contain it in a single shape while keeping the non-destructive nature of the blend, I started exploring halves and then later mirrored them to achieve the shape, but they seemed very boxy and sharp and not to forget the irregular blend lines.
   [image: E explorations]

but this broke the earlier constraint that I started with (to have closed shapes).
After a lot of trials, I settled for
[image]

5. After a few days, I dismiss these letters because they had elements that did not seem fit for this set.
6. I tightened the constraints and made sure that all the letters had the same stem width, the same stroke caps, similar curves and similar blend lines, result was [image: Reaslisation] (exceptions C and G, I like them wider than the rest)

### As a result, I have managed to follow the constraint, but the design suffers, I don't like the current H, M and N (they all are dependent on "I", help me find a suitable "I" for this set., please)

---

### Observations

- (left) When I squint my eyes/ look from a distance/ look at the mirror images/ blur the shapes, i notice the shapes aren't balanced, here the M, N and H looks very similar and are not legible
- (middle) When I invert the stroke color to black and give a bg of white, it just looks hideous. I felt like puking :(
- (right) filling the shapes create a good look imo.

[image: Observations]

---

### Next steps

- I am thinking of exploring ribbon like overlapping qualities

[image: looks shady I know] but it just looks awful to me

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done a great job! The alphabet is a real mixture of shapes and not everything will fit into a specific geometric style.

It's not directly related but Jonathan Hoefler did a [neat explanation here](https://youtu.be/7VnFNooWgD0?t=78) about how reusing the same forms for every letter becomes a straitjacket.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I found this on your profile, https://www.printmag.com/featured/flawed-typefaces/
such a fun read.

About the answer, I follow what you mean by "becoming a straitjacket", I am realizing it, my notion was "structure sets you free" and I just knew that whatever happens I need to keep the traits same for all the characters. 

If you were designing this type-set, what would you change? 
I was designing this on a dark background, and when I viewed it on a light bg it looked awful, how does one resolve this problem? What is the correct way to think about it?